# How do I open the Beneviento mausoleum in the graveyard?

Tags: resident-evil-village

I've finished Resident Evil Village twice now and I've noticed some inconsistent behaviors with the Beneviento Treasure. In both playthroughs I defeated the Donna Beneviento and returned to the village with the four-winged key. However, in one playthrough I was able to return to the village and the mausoleum containing the broken Beneviento headstone was unlocked by a lycan. On the other playthrough the mausoleum was never opened - thus preventing me from completing the puzzle and fighting the axe-weilding Urias miniboss.

What is required to open the mausoleum in the Village graveyard? It doesn't seem like only defeating Donna Beneviento is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must visit the mausoleum after defeating Donna but before progressing further. If you progress to the next area then the mausoleum never opens and you will be unable to retrieve the treasure.

You cannot get the stone slab before defeating Donna. The gate remains locked, and even if you walk all the way up to the treasure you cannot get back until you defeat Donna.

The crypt then won't open if you head towards the next boss where you can no longer return to the village until defeated.

FWIW, [this page](https://www.powerpyx.com/resident-evil-8-village-all-treasure-locations-solutions/) appears to back me up on this:

> This treasure can be obtained AFTER you get the flask from Beneviento [...] This item is MISSABLE because the crypt closes later in the playthrough

Comment: This is correct in my experience, go there once you have the second flask and it'll be open. I've always gone straight there though, didn't realise it closed up.

Comment: This seems to be the only time-sensitive puzzle in the game. I wish failing it didn’t lock you out from so much content